# $\min f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^t Bx + c^t x$ subject to $Ax=b, x\ge 0$ then $f(\overline{x})=\frac{1}{2}(c^t\overline{x}+b^t\overline{\lambda})$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier

> $$\min f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^t Bx + c^t x\\\mbox{s.t.} \\Ax=b\\ x\ge 0$$
>
> Let $\overline{x}$ be a regular solution of the problem and
>   $\overline{\lambda}$ the vector of Lagrange Multipliers associated to
>   the equality restrictions.
>
> Prove that
>   $f(\overline{x})=\frac{1}{2}(c^t\overline{x}+b^t\overline{\lambda})$

This problem is the same as

$$\min f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^t Bx + c^t x\\\mbox{s.t.} \\Ax-b\le 0\\ -x\le 0$$

I can't use advances method like KKT or whatever, so to solve problems with inequality constraints I must create a matrix with all the inequalities and analyze the intersection points. That is, the points $x$ such that $a_ix-b_i= 0$ and $a_jx-b_j= 0$ for some $i$ and $j$ or that $a_ix-b_i= 0$ and $-x\le 0$. I must investigate if the points $x$ in the intersection are written like this: $\nabla f(x) = B_I\lambda$, where $B$ is the matrix of all inequalities, and $B_I$ is the submatrix of $B$ that contains only the inequalities of the intersection.

However I have some questions. The minimum point will always be in the intersections? If it's true, how do I arrive at the final result? If $\overline{x}$ is a point in the intersection of two inequalities and satisfy $\nabla f(\overline{x})=B_I\overline{\lambda}$ for negative $\lambda_i$ for all $i$ then how $f(\overline{x})=\frac{1}{2}(c^t\overline{x}+b^t\overline{\lambda})$?

Comment: what does a Lagrange Multiplier mean to you when you cannot use 'KKT or whatever'?

Comment: @LinAlg I don't know what KKT means but I've seen in the related questions. A Lagrange multiplier is the terms of $\lambda$ in $\nabla f(x) = B_I\lambda$

Comment: What else do you know about the multiplier? Obviously you will have to use some condition such as $Bx + c + A^T \lambda = 0$.

Comment: @LinAlg I know that a necessary condition for $x$ to be minimum is that $\nabla f(x) = B_I\lambda$ where $\lambda_i<0$ for all $i$ and $B_I$ is the submatrix of $B$ with only the active contraints in $x$, that is, the ones that passes through $x$. $B$ is the matrix with all constraints

Comment: that leads to $Bx+c = A^T \lambda$, but you need to relate $\lambda$ to $b$ somehow (for $b^T \lambda$).

Comment: @LinAlg ok, so $\nabla f(x) = Bx+c$ and $\nabla f(x) = B_I\lambda$ for it to be a minimum. We need to solve for the $x$ that satisfies $Bx+c = B_I\lambda\implies $? I don't know if $B$ is invertible. I also dind't understand, is 'you need to relate $λ$ to $b$ somehow' a hint? I'm trying to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KKT conditions are: if $x$ reaches $\min(f)$, then there are $2$ vectors $\lambda,\mu$ s.t.

$Bx+c=A^T\lambda+\mu$ and satisfying the relations $x_i\mu_i=0$ (also $\mu$ has a constant signum, that here is useless).

Thus $x^TBx+x^Tc=x^TA^T\lambda+x^T\mu=b^T\lambda$.

Then $f(x)=1/2x^TBx+c^Tx=1/2c^Tx+1/2b^T\lambda$.

Comment: I've never seen the relations $x_i\mu_i=0$. Where do they come from?

Comment: why $x^TA^T\lambda+x^T\mu=b^T\lambda$?

Comment: ok, I see why $x^TA^T\lambda+x^T\mu=b^T\lambda$, that's because of the relation $x_i\mu_i=0$, but I've never seen this relation

Comment: @Paprika , See      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions    and the chapter "complementary slackness".